# RxJava expiring subscription

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I want to react to an event if it's within a certain time window and only once. Right now, the code looks like:

```
mServiceRestartEmitter.take(1).subscribe(action);
```

However, I want the action not only to unsubscribe after the event was consumed 1x, but also if the event is not happening within the next say 300ms.
How would one achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized that the `take()` operator also allows for a time constraint:

```
mServiceRestartEmitter.take(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).take(1).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(action);
```

should do the trick.